# Magento clean install is now doing this during Setup:Static-content:deploy

Tags: static-content-deploy, duplicate

A fairly new and clean install on a dev platform.
Magento 2.3.1 using the latest porto theme.
PHP 7.2

Running setup:static-content:deploy seems to be running duplicate versions of each of the themes installed. (Luma, Blank, Porto, Porto RTL and so on....)
I think that this is related or the cause of why I have multiple copies of the same image in the pub/media/catalog/product/....
Inside the catalog folder there are;

image_2.jpg

image_2_1.jpg

image_2_2.jpg

image_2_3.jpg

image_2_4.jpg

image_2_5.jpg

So far I have only created a few simple and configurable products, but at this rate with so many duplicates I'm going to run out of disk space.

Does anyone know what is causing the default deployment to multiply like this, and can anyone tell me if these are directly linked - or how to solve both\either?

[image: strange duplicated deployment behaviour]

Comment: Any updates on this duplication behavior?